# How can app on iPhone pair and connec with BT periphral from within the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

For example: Pebble application on iPhone allows me to brows a list of discovered BT devices and then pair and connect to the watch.
I know how to show the list of BT peripherals, but I was sure that pairing and connecting from code is impossible.

**Example for desired behavior:**

[image]

[image]

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why it was down voted. If you don't know the answer, that's not a reason to down vote. This question is legit!

Comment: Your question isn't clear, and is very broad. Why the `pebble-watch` tag? Are you building an app with PebbleKit for iOS? A generic iOS app? What does "connect with BT peripheral" mean? Do you want to use a Bluetooth microphone? Get data from an exercise monitor band? Send low-level Bluetooth packets manually? Build your own UI for managing Bluetooth devices to replace the stock one? Please be *specific*, and ideally provide the code that's giving you trouble.

Comment: I might agree with the `pebble-watch` tag comment (removed), but not with all the rest. It doesn't really matter what application I'm trying to build or what type of peripheral I'm trying to connect to. My question is clear: It's about pairing and connecting from the application.

Comment: Seems to be Bluetooth Low-Energy...

Comment: @Larme - Not only. Pebble has LE AND regular BT. The Pebble companion app is pairing and connecting to both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you are trying to do using EAAccessoryManager class's

- (void)showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:(NSPredicate *)predicate completion:(EABluetoothAccessoryPickerCompletion)completion

if you call this method with nil in both arguments, you will get the exact dialog you show above from the pebble app.

good luck